# How to enable Suspended Billing When Creating a New Classic Virtual Server via ibmcloud CLI

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Using the `ibmcloud` CLI, how do I specify Suspended billing?

I am trying to create two identical VM instances, the first via the GUI and the second via the `ibmcloud` CLI.

Classic Infrastructure.

CLI command:

```
ibmcloud sl vs create -H ibm -D example.com -c 1 -m 2048 -d dal13 -o UBUNTU_18_64 --disk 25 --san
```

When I compare the two instances in the GUI, they are identical except for hostname, IP addresses and Suspended billing. The are also identical when using the CLI command `ibmcloud sl vs detail ID`.

The problem I am trying to solve is: instances created with the CLI have Suspending billing as Unavailable. Instances created thru the GUI have Suspended billing as Enabled on Power Off.

This [link](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cli?topic=cloud-cli-cli-virtual-servers#sl_vs_create) is the documentation that I am using for creating an instance with the CLI. No mention of Suspended billing options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem, but I am very open to additional information. Please comment if you know the link to any documentation on this matter.

It appears that you must select a preconfigured virtual server instance type called "flavor" to enabled suspended billing. I could not find any clear documentation on this, but I saw this in API calls [link](https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/vsiflavors/).

I found this command which lists the flavors available:

```
ibmcloud sl vs options
```

This CLI command creates an instance with suspended billing enabled. Notice the use of the `--flavor` command line option:

```
ibmcloud sl vs create -H ibm2 -D example.com --flavor B1_1X2X25 -d dal13 -o UBUNTU_18_64 --san
```